# PhpStorm Deployment Mappings: Deployment Path and Web Path

Tags: deployment, path, phpstorm, webfaction

I'm trying to set up deployment to a Webfaction server.

> Preferences>Build, Execution, Deployment>Deployment>Mappings:

Should both Deployment Path and Web Path point to the

> /home/user/webapps/'my_webapp'

directory?

Comment: As simple as "No" -- those a two **different** settings, regardless of the web server software used.

Comment: "Deployment Path" is what folder IDE need to travel/change after it will log in into the service (e.g. FTP). "Web Path" is what part of the path (URL) you see when you open it in browser. Inmost cases web path will be just "/"

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  I was initally confused by the phpstorm website saying this about Web Path:  "Actually, type the relative path you typed in the Deployment Path text box."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the example of how you can set up the deployment mapping in PhpStorm, with one folder for the public files (accessible to the browser), and one folder for the server-side resources (cannot be accessed over HTTP). The web-path for the latter does not play any role of course, since it is not seen on the web.

[image: PhpStorm screenshot]